# Error when executing make

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to create a makefile for my project, but i seem to run into some errors, as I am testing new things. My file structure is as such:

```
~/main   #root project folder
    ~/main/include   #header files (mostly class headers)
    ~/main/src       #source files
    ~/main/src/obj   #object files
    Makefile
```

(Makefile is in the root project folder)

**Makefile:**

```
CC=g++

IDIR=include
SDIR=src
ODIR=src/obj

DEPS=$(IDIR)/%.h
OBJS=$(ODIR)/%.o
SRCS=$(SDIR)/%.cpp

CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++11 -I$(IDIR)

$(OBJS): $(SRCS) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

all: $(OBJS)
    gcc -o run $^ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

For testing purposes I have a single `main.cpp` in `src` folder and a random header file in `include` folder. The error I am getting when running the simple `make` command is the following:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `src/obj/%.o', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

**EDIT :** With the help of the guys below i came up with the solution

```
CC=g++

IDIR=include
SDIR=src
ODIR=src/obj

CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++11 -I$(IDIR)

_DEPS = yo.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

_SRC = main.cpp
SRC = $(patsubst %,$(SDIR)/%,$(_SRC))


$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SRC) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

all: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o run $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in using `%` in your two cases. When you write:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o : $(SDIR)/%.cpp $(IDIR)/%.h
```

that will do pattern substitution, and create a bunch of rules like:

```
$(ODIR)/foo.o : $(SDIR)/foo.cpp $(SDIR)/foo.h
```

So it's fine there, although you should use the `%` explicitly there so it's clear to see what the rule is doing.

But when you use it here:

```
all : $(ODIR)/%.o
```

That is literally looking for the target `$(ODIR)/%.o` for which you don't have a rule. There's no substitution. And you don't have a rule to make that target - hence the error. What you meant to do was have `all` depend on all the actual objects, for which you'll want to use the `wildcard` function:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:$(SDIR)/%.cpp=$(ODIR)/%.o)

all : $(OBJECTS)
    gcc -o run $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: nice seems to be working! will mark it when i test properly

Comment: Okay compiles fine, although it seems that it doesn't place the .o files under the `obj` folder. Can that be done from the makefile itself, or should I do it manually?

Comment: @LeFrillo Huh? Where does it place them?

Comment: @LeFrillo Oh woops, fixed the objects definition.

Comment: well sorry to keep you here, but we are back at the first error, with that fix. :(

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target 'src/obj/main.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop.

Comment: @LeFrillo Do you still have the `$(ODIR)/%.o` rule?

Comment: My makefile is the same as in the question. I only added the SOURCES and OBJECTS vars (the ones in your post), above the `all` rule and changed its prerequisite to `$(OBJECTS)`

Comment: basically i deleted my `all` rule and replaced it with your code segment

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
OBJS=$(ODIR)/%.o
```

The `%.o` part does not expand to anything meaningful. It just remains as the literal value `%.o`. Same problem exists for `DEPS` and `SRCS` as well.

You need to use the `wildcard` and `patsub` functions. Instead of

```make
DEPS=$(IDIR)/%.h
OBJS=$(ODIR)/%.o
SRCS=$(SDIR)/%.cpp
```

use

```make
DEPS=$(wildcard $(IDIR)/*.h)
SRCS=$(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS=$(patsub %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))
```

Comment: `gcc -o run  -Wall -std=c++11 -Iinclude`

`gcc: fatal error: no input files`

`compilation terminated.`

`make: *** [all] Error 4`

Comment: Under the rules for target `all`, add some debugging commands, `echo $(SRCS)` and `echo $(OBJS)` to make sure that the `wildcard` function picks up the correct values.